# Links do not go to relevant page

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

I wanted to make links active through JQUERY when they are clicked.

I found the code from stackoverflow. It's working fine for me but when I click on my links they get bold or active as I want but the link doesn't go to its relevant page, i.e,

```
<li><a href="term-conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
```

So, when I click on T&C link it doesn't work but the link gets active.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: Try to remove e.preventDefault();

Comment: were do you open the links? new page, iframe, were?

Comment: Doesn't sound very usefull to add / remove a class if you want to follow the link, unless you open it in an iframe as @Sergio said or it is a hashtag within the page.

Comment: @Sergio I open the new page

Comment: @VIKASHATWAL, why add a new class if you navigate away from page to the next page?

Comment: @Sergio The navigation file is common. Cannot do it individually.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
     $('li a').click(function() {
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return true;
       });
    });//]]>  

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `e.preventDefault();` which will stop the link event from happening. You need to remove it. Or keep the code and add `document.location = a.href;` to the bottom.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        **document.location = $('a').attr('href');**
    });
});//]]>
```

Comment: I removed that too and the links are working now. But then now the links are not getting active. What should I do for that? Thanks

Comment: Well, if the page is changing, then the user won't have much of a chance to see the CSS change. It may be an iframe your loading, in which case you need to capture the href and load it yourself. I've changed my example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how `e.preventDefault();` works. It prevents the default behaviour of your link, so the action to go to your desired destination. Try to remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in the load function

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li a').click(function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();        
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/twjSJ/1/

Comment: Check you CSS also, You can check the running code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you open a new page I dont see the point of adding a new class and on the same second navigate away from it. So I think you want to open them on a iFrame. If that is the case, try this:

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#frameID").prop("src", $(this).prop('href'));
    });
});
```